# Django multiple jQuery Ajax html responses

Tags: python, jquery, django, ajax

I have a jQuery ajax call like this to get an html response and popolate an html div

```
function loadProducts(url){
    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url: url,
        data:{
            data1: xxx
        },
        dataType:"html",success:function(a){
            $('#div1').html(a);
        }
    })
}
```

Django response in python is like this

```
def call_view(request):

   if request.method == "POST":
      return render(request, 'file1.html', {
            'val1': val1,
            'val2': val2
        })
```

I would like to handle multiple html blocks in jQuery response like this and popolate more than one html div

i tried this..

```
function loadProducts(url){
    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url: url,
        data:{
            data1: xxx
        },
        dataType:"html",success:function(a){
            $('#div1').html(a.resp1);
            $('#div2').html(a.resp2);
        }
    })
}
```

and this

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def call_view(request):

    if request.method == "POST":
      return {
       'resp1': render(request, 'file1.html', {
            'val1': val1,
            'val2': val2
        }),

       'resp2': render(request, 'file2.html', {
            'val3': val3,
            'val4': val4
        })
     }
```

but doesn't work
any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

i solved parsing multiple objects in one html response like this.. but i don't like

```
$.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:url,
        data:{
            ...
        },
        dataType:"html",success:function(a){
            $('#div1').html($($.parseHTML(a)).filter("#div1"));
            $('#div2').html($($.parseHTML(a)).filter("#div2"));
        }
    })
```